# Error when assembling for AT91SAM9261EK

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, keil, gcc3

I am trying to compile an assembly program using the keil uVision platform. The program issupposed to run on an AT91SAM9261EK (I have modified the settings as intended) but I get the following error.

```
c:\Cygnus\Arm-Tools\lib\gcc-lib\arm-thumb-elf\3.3.1\collect2.exe: *** heap allocated but not at 0x7A0000
      2 [main] collect2 5428 sync_with_child: child 2964(0x124) died before initialization with status code 0x1 
  35657 [main] collect2 5428 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
collect2: ld returned 255 exit status
c:\Cygnus\Arm-Tools\lib\gcc-lib\arm-thumb-elf\3.3.1\collect2.exe: *** heap allocated but not at 0x7A0000
      2 [main] collect2 5428 sync_with_child: child 2964(0x124) died before initialization with status code 0x1
  35657 [main] collect2 5428 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
```

Comment: Looks like the linker is crashing.  Toolchain corruption/misinstallation problem?

Comment: the process of installing and setting up the compiler with the right settings is clearly explained in the manual I have. I've done it in two separate computers. Same process. Same steps. I get the same error.

Comment: It looks like you've two different versions of `cygwin1.dll` installed on your machine.

Comment: Nitpicky but true: "compiling" an assembly program is called "assembling."

Comment: @RossRidge That seemed to be the problem. I had a gnuarm4.10 installed in my computer for some reason and it seemed to interfere with the gccarm3.3.1. that I am supposed to use. Unistalled it and problem was fixed. Thanks for the help